# Overpass Turbo: how to get public transport routes and stops with stop names?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-turbo

I am searching metro and tram routes and stops, example Bilbao.

With overpass turbo wizard on https://overpass-turbo.eu , I use

```
type=route and route=tram or type=route and route=subway
```

to create

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was: 
“type=route and route=tram or type=route and route=subway” 
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “type=route and route=tram”
  node["type"="route"]["route"="tram"]({{bbox}});
  way["type"="route"]["route"="tram"]({{bbox}});
  relation["type"="route"]["route"="tram"]({{bbox}});
  // query part for: “type=route and route=subway”
  node["type"="route"]["route"="subway"]({{bbox}});
  way["type"="route"]["route"="subway"]({{bbox}});
  relation["type"="route"]["route"="subway"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

(I changed to "out meta" to get maximum results)

The example is from Bilbao.

I export to geojson, which gives me almost what I need except on thing:

this is how a tram stop looks like:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "node/5478168779",
    "@relations": [
      {
        "role": "stop",
        "rel": 8753521,
        "reltags": {
          "colour": "green",
          "from": "Bolueta",
          "name": "T1 (Bolueta → La Casilla)",
          "network": "Euskotren Tranbia",
          "network:wikidata": "Q123955",
          "network:wikipedia": "eu:Euskotren Tranbia",
          "operator": "Euskotren",
          "operator:wikidata": "Q3061020",
          "operator:wikipedia": "eu:Eusko Trenbideak",
          "public_transport:version": "2",
          "ref": "T1",
          "route": "tram",
          "to": "La Casilla",
          "type": "route",
          "wheelchair": "yes",
          "wikidata": "Q2661356",
          "wikipedia": "en:Bilbao tram"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -2.9287285,
      43.2663144
    ]
  },
  "id": "node/5478168779"
},
```

This is how the stop looks in OpenStreetMap:

[image]

(original data source: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/5478168779 )

OSM has tags, especially the name, that are missing in the geojson export.

How do I get the tags like

```
name: "Uribitarte"
network: "Euskotren Tranbia"
operator: "Eusko Trenbideak"
```

Into the geojson export?

Comment: Perhaps misreading your question,  Is the data you want in the json created by overpass prior to exporting to geojson?

Comment: @nmtoken when I export using the "OSM raw data" option, there is no String "Uribitarte" in the resulting file as shown here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/5478168779 if this is not what you want to know, how do I see what you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Stops are emitted by the generated

```
out skel qt;
```

Option

```
skel
```

Removes the tags.

The solution is to use

```
out qt;
```